# VBA giving wrong date format

Tags: date-format

I have a cell in a worksheet that uses VBA code to auto-enter the date that a new contact is added.  Throughout the second half of July when I coded the macro, I have had no problems, but for some reason is has switch from UK to US date format.

The line of code is:
`Cells(intCounter, 7).Value = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")`

Why is this returning `08/01/2023` instead of `01/08/2023`, and how do I fix it?

I tried manually formatting the cells, and this has made no difference.  Also, I do not want to have to do this anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The VBA code you provided is using the "dd/mm/yyyy" format, which is the UK date format. However, if your computer's regional settings are set to the US format (mm/dd/yyyy), the code will interpret the date accordingly.

if you dont want to change regional setting you can try using

```
Cells(intCounter, 7).Value = Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy", vbUseSystemDayOfWeek)
```

Comment: My regional settings are all UK, not Us.